# How to print number 1 to 31 with three threads in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print number 1 to 31 In order with Three Threads.
When the number became 31, I want to output "(current Thread) defeated."
Also the number can be output up to 3.

So I want to output like

Thread One print: 1 2
Thread Two print: 3 4 5
Thread Three print: 6 7
Thread One print: 8
......
Thread Three print: 31
Thread Three defeat

and program ends.

```
    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    Stack sta = new Stack();
    
    public void run() {
        while(sta.getStack()<=31){
            int stack = 1;
            stack++;
            
            sta.setStack(stack);
            
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "print: "+ stack);
            
        }
        
    }

}
////////////

        public class Stack {
        private int stack = 1;
        
        public synchronized void setStack (int stack) {
            for(int cnt = 1; cnt<=31; cnt ++) {
                
            try {
                 
                Thread.sleep(100);
                
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                
            }
            
        
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "defeated.");
            
        }
            
    }
        public int getStack() {
            return this.stack;
        }
    
    }

////////////////////

    public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Runnable threadRun = new MyRunnable();
        
        Thread myThread1 = new Thread(threadRun);
        Thread myThread2 = new Thread(threadRun);
        Thread myThread3 = new Thread(threadRun);
        
        myThread1.setName("Thread One");
        myThread2.setName("Thread Two");
        myThread3.setName("Thread Three");
        

        myThread1.start();
        myThread2.start();
        myThread3.start();


    }

}
```

I made 3 classes.
But it prints only "Thread One output defeat"
I don't know what is problem.
It won't print Thread in order.
I'm not good at using this platform so sorry for looking weird.

Comment: First issue that I can see: the variable "int stack" inside the class Stack should be atomic. Even if you synchronized the setStack method to write on its value, memory effects are not propagated meaning that Thread 1 may have increased this variable by 1, but memory may not have been synchronized for Thread 2 and 3 on this new value.

Comment: Currently, the setStack method is synchronized, so as soon as thread 1 gets access to it, it lock everyone else out, meaning Thread one will complete the whole method before letting the other threads use it. Edit: As pointed out by @Matteo NNZ, the value of the int is not same for the three threads.

Comment: @JhanzaibHumayun that's correct. But the modifications done to the variable int stack by thread 1 are not necessarily propagated to the memory cache of Thread 2 and 3 if the variable is not volatile. So variable may have value X for the thread that modified it and X-1 for the other threads.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ as long as all access to a variable is properly `synchronized`, there is no need for `volatile`. So the problem here is that the `getStack()` method is not `synchronized`. And that every thread uses its own local variable anyway.

Comment: “*But it prints only ‘Thread One output defeat’ I don't know what is problem*”—because that’s precisely what you told the computer to do. Your `setStack` method calls `Thread.sleep(100);` 31 times, which does nothing but cause a delay, then it prints `Thread.currentThread().getName() + "defeated."`. There’s nothing else in this method, hence, there’s nothing else to expect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit and came up with this:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
Stack sta = new Stack();

@Override
public void run() {
    while (sta.getStack() <= 31) {
        int stack = sta.getStack() + 1;
        sta.setStack(stack);

        if (stack <= 31) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " print: " + stack);
        }
    }
}
}

public class Stack {
private int stack = 0;

public synchronized void setStack(int stack) {
    this.stack = stack;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    if (stack > 31) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " defeated.");
    }
}

public synchronized int getStack() {
    return this.stack;
}
}

public class ThreadTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable threadRun = new MyRunnable();

    Thread myThread1 = new Thread(threadRun);
    Thread myThread2 = new Thread(threadRun);
    Thread myThread3 = new Thread(threadRun);

    myThread1.setName("Thread One");
    myThread2.setName("Thread Two");
    myThread3.setName("Thread Three");

    myThread1.start();
    myThread2.start();
    myThread3.start();

}
}
```

Comment: A typical case of the “lost updates” problem. Between `getStack()` and `setStack(…)`, anything can happen, including updates made by other threads which get overwritten.

Comment: I think I don't know anything about overriding and synchronize. Thank for your effort and I need to study more